# Domain parking in Hypernode/Ngix server

Tags: nginx, dns, cloud, magento-1.9, nginx-location

I have a domain that already setup for byte.nl hypernode server:

you can see details at:http://network-tools.com/default.asp?prog=express&host=lerenjas.nl

But I still couldn't access using lerenjas.nl and I can access by 'http://europell.hypernode.io/' what could be problem. any help would be great.

I already tried many things.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing nginx has to do in this case. Your DNS is not set for lerenjas.nl. When you check it in the network tool url you have provided, it says "lookup failed". But for hypernode.io, lookup is successful.

So, you will have to check the byte.nl name servers.